# I can't change the label editing text in swift launch screen

Tags: swift, uikit, launch, launch-screen

Hi I put a label on launch screen . When the application is first opened, I want it to write Welcome on the label.
I want the label to write Hello on the next logins of the user.

After making the first assignment to the label, I could not find how to change it, where to define the label

Comment: The launch screen has no code associated with it. It is just an image. There is no way to change it programmatically. The intended use of the launch screen is to show an empty representation of the app so that it looks like the app opens instantly.

Comment: What you are trying should not be done on the Launch screen... You can create new view controller which will be the first view controller of the app and write text there based on logged in status...